# How to delete Instances in Amazon EC2 ? Change Pair Key?

Tags: amazon-ec2

How to remove Instances ? I test some Instances and now I terminate it. So, I want to remove it. I can't find delete or remove action. I just found terminate.

How to change the pair key ? I don't have pair key for old Instances and I want to configure that instances.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If your instance uses the instance store as its root device (e.g. it's not an EBS backed instance), simply terminating it will destroy the instance and you won't have to do anything else.

Comment: can I change pair key ? I want to use one Instances but I don't have pem for Instances.

Comment: Keypairs can be managed through the AWS console : http://aws.amazon.com/console/

Comment: Yes, in Instance , I found Key Pair name but I don't know how to change it. I crate new key pair from NETWORKING & SECURITY > Key Pairs. I want to use my new key pairs.

Thank

Comment: and if it is EBS backed?

Comment: wow, this answer is really vague.  im trying out EC2 for the first time today and I am noticing right away that once you create an instance, if you terminate it, it will still appear in your list as a re-usable instance.  there doesn't seem to be a way to delete instances.  Is There?

Comment: The docs seem to indicate that there is a command line tool you can use to delete an instance, but I can't find clear instructions.

Comment: @djangofan A terminated instance is automatically removed from the list in a short while, and doesn't cost anything.

Answer (score 58):

Give it some time. Deletion of terminated instances is not a high priority task within the EC2 stack (seems reasonable to me). Eventually the terminated instance will drop out of the interface.

Comment: I have an instance that has been terminated for months, and it's still in the list.

Comment: I'd like to correct my last comment. I had an instance that was "stopped" for months. Changing the status to terminated does make it go away, given time. Now I understand "termination protection". Semantics!

Comment: What is a reasonable time before opening a support case?
Mine is stuck in terminated for nearly 6 weeks now.

Comment: It takes a few minutes (less than ten as per my experience). You need to check if termination protection is enabled. Google it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to worry about it. It will disappear after some time from the UI Interface.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the response from the Amazon team. This should solve your issue regarding instance deletion:

To terminate an instance please visit:

https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=us-west-2#Instances:sort=instanceId

The t2.micro can be deleted by right clicking, going to instance state and selecting terminate.

The t1.micro can be deleted by visiting:

https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=us-west-2#LoadBalancers:

Right click the Elastic Load Balancer, select delete. Then repeat the steps listed above for the t2.micro.

Answer (score -3):

Yes if you hit refresh button on the console it will disapear.

Comment: nope. that's not it.